# How to make multiple rows from single row in pig for movie lens dataset

Tags: apache-pig

I want to divide a single row into multiple row on the basis of a field in pig.

Example:
Consider one of the row in movie Data Set as follows:

(31807, Dot the I (2003), Drama|Film-Noir|Thriller)

each field is separated by ','.

Desired Output is as follows in 3 different rows:

31807,Dot the I (2003),Drama

31807,Dot the I (2003),Film-Noir

31807,Dot the I (2003),Thriller

Can anyone please help me to get the desired output in pig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below logic will help you .

```
 /* Input 

     (31807,Dot the I (2003),Drama|Film-Noir|Thriller)

 */

 list = LOAD '/user/cloudera/movies.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,name:chararray,generes:chararray);

 list_each = FOREACH list GENERATE id,name, flatten(TOKENIZE(generes,'|'));

 dump list_each;


 /* Output 

    (31807,Dot the I (2003),Drama)
    (31807,Dot the I (2003),Film-Noir)
    (31807,Dot the I (2003),Thriller)

 */
```